# Reading OCR/ OMR with C#

Tags: c#, ocr

I need to capture some feedback from a printed paper form. It contains choices to mark and may be some handwritten texts. Completed feedback forms should be scanned/ processed using an OCR tool and stored in a MS SQL Server database.

The system is developed using C#.Net.

Please let me know some your experience. BTW, what about Abbyy FineReader for this?

Comment: This isn't really a good question for stackoverflow.  You should ask quesoitns that have a factual answer rather than a debate around what tool is best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are talking about OMR aka Form processing. You will need a toolkit having following features:

- OMR /Form processing to read optical marks
- ICR to read hand written text
- Image processing, to perform image pre - processing to correct image before processing

I had used atalasoft OMR, capturing, image processing and  IRIS OCR, ICR.

Good paid solutions:

- Abbyy FineReader is good option Atalasoft (basic /intermediate) OMR 
  feature, great  capture and image processing features.
- Leatools -    provides OMR, OCR, ICR
- IRIS (iDRS ocr Engine). difficult to program  but great quality OCR, ICR features.

Answer (score 0):

Like Needo mentioned, there are commercial toolkits that supports OCR\OMR technology. We tried some of them and ended up using leadtools and it helped us to capture data from our surveys. You can find more here:
http://support.leadtools.com/CS/forums/37869/ShowPost.aspx